# Is there any option for vertical navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. I want to make a widget which is marked in red in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzXuc.png).
I tried using Transform but the widgets (Text widgets for 'Overview', 'Portfolio', etc.) are overlapping on each other.
How can I build it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RotatedBox with quarterTurns 3

```
RotatedBox(quarterTurns: 3, child: Text('Overview'))
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RotatedBox(quarterTurns: 3, child: Text('Overview')),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RotatedBox(quarterTurns: 3, child: Text('Profile')),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RotatedBox(quarterTurns: 3, child: Text('Bio')),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Flutter has `NavigationRail`. You can see sample and documentation from their [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html).

Flutter added this support as it becomes standard in Material design 3 [here](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-rail).

Just keep attention to their usage recommendations.

> The navigation rail is meant for layouts with wide viewports, such as a desktop web or tablet landscape layout. For smaller layouts, like mobile portrait, a BottomNavigationBar should be used instead.

And below is sample flutter code for your convenience.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0xff6750a4), useMaterial3: true),
      home: const NavRailExample(),
    );
  }
}

class NavRailExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavRailExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavRailExample> createState() => _NavRailExampleState();
}

class _NavRailExampleState extends State<NavRailExample> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  NavigationRailLabelType labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.all;
  bool showLeading = false;
  bool showTrailing = false;
  double groupAligment = -1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            NavigationRail(
              selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
              groupAlignment: groupAligment,
              onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
              labelType: labelType,
              leading: showLeading
                  ? FloatingActionButton(
                      elevation: 0,
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Add your onPressed code here!
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    )
                  : const SizedBox(),
              trailing: showTrailing
                  ? IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Add your onPressed code here!
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz_rounded),
                    )
                  : const SizedBox(),
              destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                  selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                  label: Text('First'),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                  selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
                  label: Text('Second'),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.star_border),
                  selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.star),
                  label: Text('Third'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
            // This is the main content.
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('selectedIndex: $_selectedIndex'),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text('Label type: ${labelType.name}'),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  OverflowBar(
                    spacing: 10.0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.none;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text('None'),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.selected;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text('Selected'),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.all;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text('All'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text('Group alignment: $groupAligment'),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  OverflowBar(
                    spacing: 10.0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            groupAligment = -1.0;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text('Top'),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            groupAligment = 0.0;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text('Center'),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            groupAligment = 1.0;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text('Bottom'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  OverflowBar(
                    spacing: 10.0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            showLeading = !showLeading;
                          });
                        },
                        child:
                            Text(showLeading ? 'Hide Leading' : 'Show Leading'),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            showTrailing = !showTrailing;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(
                            showTrailing ? 'Hide Trailing' : 'Show Trailing'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```